# Correct date format for xAxis on highcharter drilldown chart in R

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm having some trouble getting the correct format for my x-axis in the drill-down chart. I'm hoping to have the same x-axis formatting as the 'drilled-up' chart (e.g. "mmm-yy"). Below is a minimal example.

At the moment, it looks like there is no data being used for the drilled-down x-axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(highcharter); library(dplyr)
myData <- tibble(name = c("Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog"),
                     value = c(2,3,2,5),
                     date = as.Date(c("2021-03-01", "2021-06-01","2021-03-01", "2021-06-01")),
                     drilldown = tolower(name) )

hc <- hchart(myData, "column", hcaes( y = value, group=name, x = date)) %>%   
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = "normal"))

myDataDrilldown <- tibble(date = as.Date(c("2021-03-01", "2021-06-01")),
                              value = c(4, 3)) %>%
  list_parse2()

hc %>% hc_drilldown(
  allowDrilldown = TRUE,
  series = list(
    list(id = "cat",
         data = myDataDrilldown)
  )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: which one is drill up and which one is drill down chart? I see only one x-axis which has values April'21 and Jul'21.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, clicking on the "Cat" category in the bar chart will drill down to another chart that shows 1.Jan on the x-axis. It should be 1.Mar.

Comment: Ahh..I see but for me clicking on "Cat" produces x-axis with the same values which is Apr'21 and Jul'21.